# Saving promise resolve function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, promise

I have been trying to make a event-emitter using ES6 promises, but when the saved response is called the second time it doesn't return anything.

```
var z;
function test(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        z = resolve;
    });
}

test().then(()=> console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa') )

console.log(z) // ƒ () { [native code] }
z(); // aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
z(); // <empty>
```

Comment: It's the nature of promises that they only contain one single value. A promise can resolve only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the saved response is called the second time

Promises are only settled **once**. Once a promise is settled (resolved or rejected), that's it; its state never changes again. Subsequent calls to the `resolve` and `reject` functions passed to the promise executor are ignored. (Some would prefer that they throw, but they don't.)

If you want an event emitter, a promise is just the wrong technology, since events can happen more than once.